# How do you find the location of a number in a sequence?

Tags: c++, sequence

Say that I have a sequence:
int seq[4][4];
Then, lets say seq[1][2]=8;
No other values of the sequence yields 8.
If I want to find the values of a sequence and print out which one it is, (e.g. 1,2 and make x=1 and y=2) how can I do that? What

Comment: You search. Look at each element and see if it contains the value you want. If there is a pattern to the sequence you can exploit, you can speed up the searching by skipping elements that you know cannot contain the value you seek.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x,j;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // looping through row
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) //looping through column
    {
       if (seq[i][j] == 8) //if value matches
       {
           x = i; y = j;   //set value
           i = 4;          //set i to 4 to exit outer for loop
           break;          //exit inner for loop
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberBeingSearchedFor = *Any Value Here*;
int array[*numRows*][*numColumns*];
int firstOccuranceRow = -1, firstOccuranceColumn = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < numColumns; ++j)
    {
        if(array[i][j] == numberBeingSearchedFor)
        {
            firstOccuranceRow = i;
            firstOccuranceColumn = j;
            i = numRows; //Credit to other answer, I've never seen that :) It's cool
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(firstOccuranceRow == -1 || firstOccuranceColumn == -1)
{
   //Item was not in the array
}
```